# Generating Google App Engine Endpoints with command line

Tags: android, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been using the Google App Engine Plugin for Eclipse to generate the Android client library. It works great because it generates actual .java files, but is cumbersome because I have to manually copy them every time I make a change.

I recently tried switching over to the command line endpoints.sh tool. It generates the library, but as a .zip. In the .zip is a bunch of crap and a .jar which I can't get to integrate with my Android project.

How do I use the command line tool and generate .java files like Eclipse does?
OR
How can I use endpoints.sh in a script to automatically add the jar to my Android project?

Comment: By design, it is supposed to generate the library as a .zip file.Read [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool) for more information.